# Apache Zeppelin and Spark deploy mode options

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I understand it directly relates to the `MASTER` environment variable in `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` and whether the value is `spark://<master_ip>:7077` or `yarn-client`, but when is Apache Zeppelin running Spark in `client` mode and when in `cluster` mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is supporting three cluster manager types of `Standalone` and `Hadoop YARN` and `Apache Mesos`

And Zeppelin is supporting [4types of master](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/interpreter/spark.html#2-set-master-in-interpreter-menu) is relevant with Spark 
but Unfortunately Zeppelin doesn't support `yarn cluster` mode.